# How to sum the ordinal value of letters in a string

Tags: arrays, linq

I'm creating a function that would return the sum of index of elements in an array.

below is my code, however there's a minor error if textCondition = "aa" or any element with the same value, the function only counts it's index once. it should be (index * no. element in condition[]). is it possible to solve this in linq?

```
string textCondition = "aa";
string[] alphabet = { "", "a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z" };
string[] condition = new string[textCondition.Length];
int idx = 0;
while (idx < textCondition.Length)
{
    string con = textCondition.Substring(idx++, 1);
    condition[idx - 1] = con;
}

var sum = alphabet.Select((v, i) => new { Index = i, Value = v })
          .Where(t => condition.Contains(t.Value))
          .Select(t => t.Index)
          .ToList().Sum();
```

Comment: I don't quite get this. You're summing the indexes. This is just going to return `0 + 1 + 2 + 3 + ... + length_of_the_array - 1`. Of course, you're `where`ing it, so it won't be that exactly, but you see my point.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. what i'm trying to do is example: textcondition = "aa"; the function should return 2 because index of "a" is 1 and it appears twice in textcondition.

Comment: another example is textcondition = "aab"; the function should return "4" because index of "a" is 1 x 2(no. of element in textcondition) and index of "b" 2 x 1(no. of element in textcondition). in summary 1 + 1 + 2 = 4

Comment: Okay, I think I get it. Do you have any code that already does this and works, but just isn't LINQ yet? Or are you writing this for the first time?

Comment: that is the only code i have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I can see you just want to sum the ordinal number based on the alphabet letter. If this is the case why don't you just use the ASCII code of the character in your string, and subtract a constant value so that it will start from 1?

Lowercase 'a' is ASCII 97, so you can have the same behavior simply by subtracting 96 from your letters, provided they are all in the range [a-z].

Be aware that a string can also be seen as an IEnumerable of chars, therefore you don't have to use loops in order to get the characters, as everything can be done directly using LINQ methods.

Something like this should do:

```
textCondition.Sum(c => c - 96);
```

Or, if you want:

```
textCondition.Sum(c => c - 'a' + 1);
```

In case you just want to sum lowercase letters only, and simply skip the remaining characters, you can just filter them ahead with a Where clause.

```
textCondition.Where(c => c >= 'a' && c <= 'z').Sum(c => c - 'a' + 1);
```